# Can't login using Laravel with correct credentials

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Good day, I've been having a hard time solving this problem for almost a week now. I'm trying to login my Laravel project, the problem is it doesn't login even though the email and password (hashed in db) input is correct. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below are the code of my files for LoginController.php, login.blade.php, and web.php

**LoginController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Models\Distributor;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Session;
use Brian2694\Toastr\Facades\Toastr;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except([
            'logout',
            'locked',
            'unlock'
        ]);
    }

    public function login()
    {

    return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function username(){ return 'email_address'; 
     }


    public function authenticate(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string',
        ]);

        $email    = $request->email;
        $password = $request->password;
        
        
        if (Auth::attempt(['emailAddress'=>$email,'password'=>$password,])) {
   
            Toastr::success('Login successfully :)','Success');
            return redirect()->intended('orders.sellload');
        }elseif (Auth::attempt(['emailAddress'=>$email,'password'=>$password])) {
          
            Toastr::success('Login successfully :)','Success');
            return redirect()->intended('orders.sellload');
        }elseif (Auth::attempt(['emailAddress'=>$email,'password'=>$password,])) {
          
            Toastr::success('Login successfully :)','Success');
            return redirect()->intended('admin.distributor');
        }
        elseif (Auth::attempt(['emailAddress'=>$email,'password'=>$password])) {
          
            Toastr::success('Login successfully :)','Success');
            return redirect()->intended('admin.distributor');
        }else{
            Toastr::error('fail, WRONG USERNAME OR PASSWORD :)','Error');
            return redirect('login');
        }

    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Toastr::success('Logout successfully :)','Success');
        return redirect('login');
    }

}
```

**login.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div id="auth">
        <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
        </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
                <div id="auth-left">
                <p style="text-align:center;"><img src="assets/images/logo/icon.png" width="300" align>
                </p>
                   
                    {{-- message --}}
                    {!! Toastr::message() !!}
                   
                    <p style="text-align:center;">Welcome to John Doe Portal</p>
                    @if(session()->has('error'))
                        <div class="text-danger text-center text-bold">
                            {{ session()->get('error') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                    <br>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}" class="md-float-material">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left mb-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" placeholder="Enter email">
                            <div class="form-control-icon">
                                <i class="bi bi-person"></i>
                            </div>
                            @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left mb-4">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">
                            <div class="form-control-icon">
                                <i class="bi bi-shield-lock"></i>
                            </div>
                            @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-lg d-flex align-items-end">
                            <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="remember_me" id="remember_me" name="remember_me">
                            <label class="form-check-label text-gray-600" for="flexCheckDefault">
                                Keep me logged in
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg shadow-lg mt-5">LOG IN</button>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-12">
        </div>
          
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PhotosController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ResetPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\FormController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserManagementController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LockScreen;


Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});

Route::get('/insert', function () {
    
    $activationCodeParam=123456;
    $idParentParam=1;
    $tierParam=2;
    $store = DB::select('
    call createStore(?,?,?)',
    array(activationCodeParam,idParentParam,tierParam));
   
});


Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function()
{
    Route::get('user',function()
    {
        return view('orders.sellload');
    });
    Route::get('home',function()
    {
        return view('orders.sellload');
    });
   
});

Auth::routes();
Route::get('home',function()
{
    return view('orders.sellload');
});
// ----------------------------- home dashboard ------------------------------//
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');

// -----------------------------login----------------------------------------//
Route::get('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'authenticate']);
Route::get('/logout', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

Comment: How do you register your users?

Comment: All your `elseif` statements are useless. What is the idea behind this?

Comment: @HassanPezeshk i have CRUD functions when logged in as an admin

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yeah sorry, my mistake, those aren't supposed to be there. but even though i deleted the other parts, it still doesnt let me login

Comment: What does your users table look like?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the session refresh before your redirect.

```php
// validation here

if(Auth::attempt(['emailAddress'=>$email,'password'=>$password,])) {
   
   Toastr::success('Login successfully :)','Success');

   $request->session()->regenerate(); // refresh session

   return redirect()->intended('orders.sellload');
}


// …
```

This shouldn’t be related, but also your if-conditions don’t make sense — because they are all the same and if one matches, the other never can be reached.

Comment: tried adding the refresh session line, it still didn't work. may i ask what's the importance of refreshing the session before redirecting?

Comment: It refreshes the session to reflect the change like logged in or not. If it still doesn’t work it also could be that something is wrong with your auth and session drivers. I think the best would be to add these to the initial question too. Maybe you even want to provide a repo with a minimal production?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#regenerating-the-session-id

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing

```
if (Auth::attempt(['emailAddress'=>$email,'password'=>$password,]))
```

`emailAddress`
to `email`?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. If I change it, it will give me this error:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `distributor` where `email` = abc@abc.com limit 1)

Comment: and I wanted to add, 'emailAddress' is what's in the table in my DB, not just 'email'